# NameError: global name 'working_dir' is not defined

Tags: python, pipeline

I try to run this pipeline but in function def run_ccs(args) there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_pipeline.py", line 307, in <module>
    run_ccs(args)
  File "run_pipeline.py", line 214, in run_ccs
    % (args.threads, repo_dir, repo_dir, working_dir, args.ccs_reads, working_dir), shell=True).wait()
  NameError: global name 'working_dir' is not defined
```

The code is:

https://github.com/mjsull/COVID_pipe/blob/master/run_pipeline.py

Comment: ```working_dir``` is indeed not a global argument. You didn't define this variable in the function ```run_ccs()```.

Comment: Can you help me about the way in wich I can define propertly this variable?

Comment: You can define `working_dir` at the beginning, and note that it exists within every function using `global working_dir`. However, without diving into your code, I can't tell you what's the optimal solution for your problem

Comment: You should not supply code via URLs pointing to external hosting sites.  Rather, you should include your code, properly formatted, in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a variable inside of a function causes that variable to have "function scope".  That variable exists only between the point where it is defined and the end of the function in which it is defined.

You define a variable named `working_dir` in two of your functions.  You try to use a variable named `working_dir` in a third function named `run_ccs`, but you have not defined that variable within the scope of that function.  You can either define a variable with that name and assign it a value prior to referring to it in the function, or you can define a variable with that name at the "global scope" by defining it outside of (at the same level as) your function definitions.  One way to define it prior to use inside the function is to have the function take a parameter with that name.

Exactly how you fix this problem will be a matter of what you want your code to be doing in terms of how it comes up with the value represented by the `working_dir` variable in the `run_ccs` function.  If the values you assign to the other variables with this same name were the same, then I'd expect that you'd want to do the same thing in `run_css` that you do in the other function to come up with that value.  But since the values are different in the other two functions, I have no idea what you want the value of this variable to be in the third function.